# ORACLE 12C Grant update on a specific column not working

Tags: oracle12c, sqlplus

I'm working with Oracle 12c sqlplus. I want to grant update on just **name ** column for a role like below but I still change value in other column.

This is my code:

```
SQL> grant select,update(name) on attendance to updatename;

Grant succeeded.
```

Comment: Are you sure they don't already have full update privileges from a role or a previous direct grant? If you granted plain update before and then changed your mind and did the column-specific one, that would not have automatically revoked the previous full one. You would need to revoke the full update first, then issue the column version.

Answer (score 0):

Doing:

```
grant update(name) on attendance to updatename;
```

would not revoke a previous plain `grant update on...`. Privileges are cumulative, so if you have both `update` and `update(name)` then that would still allow any column to be modified.

You can see whether there is also a full update privilege by querying the `dba_tab_privs` or `all_tab_privs` view:

```
select *
from all_tab_privs
where grantee = 'UPDATENAME' -- uppercase unless you have a quoted identifier
and table_name = 'ATTENDANCE' -- uppercase unless you have a quoted identifier
```

You can see individual column privileges in `dba_col_privs` or `all_col_privs`.

If there has previously been a full grant then you would need to revoke that first:

```
revoke update on attendance from updatename;
grant update(name) on attendance to updatename;
```

The user could also have full update privileges on the table via a role, not a direct grant, in which case you would need to either modify the role (affecting all users with it) or revoke the role from the user.